# Does react hook component re-render when parent component re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a react hook component

```
const Child = (props) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
        // fetch data
        ...
    });

    return ( 
        //Displays fetched data
    )
}
```

Then it is used in the parent component

```
class Parent extends Component {

    render () {
        ... <Child ... /> ...
    }
}
```

My question is, if `Parent` rerenders when its state changes (but irrelevant to `Child`), would it cause the `Child` component to rerender and ultimately fetching data again?

If `Child2` has a dependency array, would it suffer the same problem?

```
const Child2 = (props) => {

    let [data, setData] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
        // fetch data
        ajax(...).then((result)=>setData(result));
    }, [data]);

    return ( 
        //Displays fetched data
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the standard behavior in react is that when a component renders, its children render too. To improve performance you can skip some renders with shouldComponentUpdate on a class component or React.memo on a functional component, but this is a performance optimization, not something you should rely on for skipping effects.

If you're fetching data in a component, you often only want to do it on mount, or only when certain relevant data changes. This is controlled with `useEffect`'s dependency array. To run it only on mount, provide an empty array `[]`. The component will still rerender when the parent component changes, but its effect will not rerun.

Comment: does the dependency array being null or empty [] makes any difference?