# Will React children update DOM when its parent rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm a bit confused with how React re-render.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState(0);

  return (

<div>
 <Child></Child>
 <button onClick={() =>setValue(value => value + 1)}>Set Value </button>
</div>

}

const Child = () => { 
   console.log('child rerender');
return (<div>Children</div>); 
}
```

so basically, when i click the button in Parent, the Parent re-render which lead to the rerender of Child component, and the console log `chid rerender`.

So my question is will `the rerender of Child Component` only means re-run the JS part (`console.log('child rerender')`), and the DOM of Child will stay the same ( without any DOM repaint and reflow) ? Or it actually unmount the Child and mount it again to DOM tree, even though its DOM content stay the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html).

The function will run, the virtual DOM will be [reconciled](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) against the real DOM, and then the real DOM won't be updated because nothing will have changed.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to care about whether React mounts and unmounts components (except in specific cases). (You can force it to do so by changing a component's `key`.)

In this case, I believe what happens to the concrete DOM is that as React does its VDOM<->DOM reconciliation, it notes that the structure of the DOM hasn't changed, nor have any text values (since the `value` isn't shown anywhere), so it does nothing to the concrete DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider this answer. Changes on parent (from hooks, internal state) causes a re-renders on child components:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290014/6182449

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33913014)